# Filtering queryset if one value is greater than another value

Tags: django

I am trying to filter in view my queryset based on relation between 2 fields .

however always getting the error that my field is not defined .

My Model has several calculated columns and I want to get only the records where values of field A are greater than field B.

So this is my model

```
class Material(models.Model):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    min_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    max_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def _get_totalinventory(self):
        from inventory.models import Inventory

       
        return Inventory.objects.filter(warehouse_Bin__material_UOM__UOM__material=self.id, is_active = true ).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))


    totalinventory = property(_get_totalinventory)

    def _get_totalpo(self):
 
        from purchase.models import POmaterial     

        return POmaterial.objects.filter(material=self.id, is_active = true).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))  

    totalpo = property(_get_totalpo)




    def _get_totalso(self):

        from sales.models import SOproduct
         
        return SOproduct.objects.filter(product__material=self.id ,  is_active=true ).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))  

    totalso = property(_get_totalpo)


    @property
    def _get_total(self):
        return (totalinventory + totalpo - totalso) 

    total = property(_get_total)
```

And this is line in my view where I try to get the conditional queryset

```
 po_list = MaterialFilter(request.GET, queryset=Material.objects.filter( total__lte =  min_quantity  ))
```

But I am getting the error that `min_quantity` is not defined

What could be the problem ?

---

EDIT:

My problem got solved thank you @Moses Koledoye but in the same code I have different issue now

> Cannot resolve keyword 'total' into field.Choices are: am, author, author_id, bom, bomversion, code, creation_time, description, id, inventory, is_active, is_production, itemgroup, itemgroup_id, keywords, materialuom, max_quantity, min_quantity, name, pomaterial, produce, product, slug, trigger_quantity, uom, updated_by, updated_by_id, valid_from, valid_to, version, warehousebin

Basically it doesn't show any of my calculated fields I have in my model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django cannot write a query which is conditioned on a field whose value is unknown. You need to use a `F` expression for this:

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset = Material.objects.filter(total__lte = F('min_quantity'))
```

And your `FilterSet` becomes:

```
po_list = MaterialFilter(request.GET, queryset = Material.objects.filter(total__lte=F('min_quantity')))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

> An **F()** object represents the value of a model field or annotated
>   column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and
>   perform database operations using them without actually having to pull
>   them out of the database into Python memory